# How to identify actual space or visible space from other type of spaces in a XML file converted from a PDF file

Tags: python, xml, pdf

When converting a PDF file into a xml file sometimes unwanted spaces in the middle of a word or sentence is found (non breaking space, zero width space etc..) in a XML file however these spaces are are not visible when they are in a pdf file what if I want to have only the actual visible spaces in the pdf to be reflected in my converted XML file by ignoring other kind of spaces

```
def convert(case, input_file_path, targetfilepath, pages=0):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set();
    else:
        pagenums = set(100);
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    caching = True

    if case == 'text':
        output = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    if case == 'HTML':
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = HTMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    if case == 'XML':
        output = io.BytesIO()
        converter = XMLConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(input_file_path, 'rb')

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    convertedPDF = output.getvalue()

    infile.close();
    converter.close();
    output.close()

    convertedFile = open(targetfilepath, 'wb')
    convertedFile.write(convertedPDF)
    convertedFile.close()


(convert('XML', input_file_path, directory_path_xml1, pages=None))
```

This is how I converted my PDF into a XML file

Comment: Thank you @KJ. I've already tried that. I assume that there's a space between letters A and B by calculating the right bounding box coordinates of letter A and the left bounding box coordinates of letter B. If the difference is less than 4 points, I consider it as an invisible space. However, the problem is that sometimes even visible spaces are less than four points, and likewise, invisible spaces are greater than 4 points. This may be due to how the PDF is created. For my tool to work to its full potential, I need to have only visible spaces in my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pdfminer.six](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/), this lines of code should create a valid XML output file:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text_to_fp
from io import BytesIO

with open('PDFSample.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    xml_output = BytesIO()
    extract_text_to_fp(pdf_file, xml_output, output_type='xml')
    xml_output.seek(0)
    xml_content = xml_output.read()

with open('output.xml', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(xml_content)

xml_output.close()
```

Comment: I can't access your link, sorry.